# Correctly using let and use in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to convert the below code from Java to Kotlin. I am not sure if my solution is the cleanest solution. I would really appreciate help.

Java (source: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v8.0/MediaProjection/andshooter/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/andshooter/ImageTransmogrifier.java)

```
@Override
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
  final Image image=imageReader.acquireLatestImage();

  if (image!=null) {
    Image.Plane[] planes=image.getPlanes();
    ByteBuffer buffer=planes[0].getBuffer();
    int pixelStride=planes[0].getPixelStride();
    int rowStride=planes[0].getRowStride();
    int rowPadding=rowStride - pixelStride * width;
    int bitmapWidth=width + rowPadding / pixelStride;

    if (latestBitmap == null ||
        latestBitmap.getWidth() != bitmapWidth ||
        latestBitmap.getHeight() != height) {
      if (latestBitmap != null) {
        latestBitmap.recycle();
      }

      latestBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapWidth,
          height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    latestBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);

    if (image != null) {
      image.close();
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Bitmap cropped=Bitmap.createBitmap(latestBitmap, 0, 0,
      width, height);

    cropped.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);

    byte[] newPng=baos.toByteArray();

    // FileOutputStream part ...
  }
}
```

Here is my Kotlin code:

```
override fun onImageAvailable(reader: ImageReader?) {
    val img: Image? = imageReader?.acquireLatestImage()

    if (img != null) {
        val planes: Array<Image.Plane> = img.planes
        val buffer: ByteBuffer = planes[0].buffer
        val pixelStride: Int = planes[0].pixelStride
        val rowStride: Int = planes[0].rowStride
        val rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * width
        val bitmapWidth = width + rowPadding / pixelStride

        val tempBitmap: Bitmap? = latestBitmap

        if (tempBitmap == null || tempBitmap.width != bitmapWidth || tempBitmap.height != height) {
            latestBitmap?.recycle()

            latestBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bitmapWidth,
                height,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            )
        }

        latestBitmap?.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer)

        img.close()

        latestBitmap?.let { bitmap ->
            val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            val cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bitmap,
                0,
                0,
                width,
                height
            )

            cropped.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos)
            val newPng: ByteArray = baos.toByteArray()

            val tempFile: File = File.createTempFile("prefix", "suffix", null)

            FileOutputStream(tempFile).use {
                it.write(newPng)
                it.flush()
                it.close()
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "[${Calendar.getInstance().time}] Saved new image to: $tempFile")
        }
    }
}
```

I had a problem with a line where I had to check if a variable is null or it's property width or height is different than the previous one. I used `tempBitmap` variable. My question is: is it ok in this form?

I also used `use` and according to documentation it can close the stream so I called `it.close` and I am also not sure if it is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things I would do even in the Java code...

First, I'd exit the method early if the image is null so you don't have to nest all your code in an if-statement. (A nice way to do this in Kotlin is `?: return`.

Second, you're neglecting to close `baos`.

Third, you're needlessly checking `if (image != null)` inside the block of another `if (image != null)`.

As for the Kotlin code, the `tempBitmap` local variable is a good strategy. But I would continue using it for the rest of the function, because the `?.let` pattern is bad for code readability when it includes more than 2-3 lines of code inisde it.

With the `use` function, there is no need to call `close`. The whole point of `use` is that it guarantees that `close` is called for you.

Was it a mistake that the `reader` parameter is ignored and you use some property called `imageReader`? Might want to check that.

Here's how I might structure the code to resolve the above points. Since I can't test this, there might be some errors.

```
fun onImageAvailable(reader: ImageReader?) {
    val img = reader?.acquireLatestImage() ?: return

    val planes: Array<Image.Plane> = img.planes
    val buffer: ByteBuffer = planes[0].buffer
    val pixelStride: Int = planes[0].pixelStride
    val rowStride: Int = planes[0].rowStride
    val rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * width
    val bitmapWidth = width + rowPadding / pixelStride
    
    var bitmap: Bitmap? = latestBitmap
    if (bitmap == null || bitmap.width != bitmapWidth || bitmap.height != height) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            bitmapWidth,
            height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )
        latestBitmap = bitmap
    }

    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer)

    img.close()

    val newPng: ByteArray
    ByteArrayOutputStream().use { baos ->
        val cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            bitmap,
            0,
            0,
            width,
            height
        )

        cropped.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos)
        newPng = baos.toByteArray()
    }

    val tempFile: File = File.createTempFile("prefix", "suffix", null)

    FileOutputStream(tempFile).use {
        it.write(newPng)
        it.flush()
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "[${Calendar.getInstance().time}] Saved new image to: $tempFile")
}
```

Comment: Indeed, `reader ` should be used instead of `imageReader`.

Comment: In this scope `ByteArrayOutputStream().use { baos -> ...` I use null-able bitmap. What would be the best solution to check it before usage?

Comment: Is it a different bitmap thing the local one above in my code? If so you could first copy it to a local val or return from the function like I did with the image on the first line.